# How to save records from one table to another table using stored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, scripting, data-migration

I have tried, but I don't know how to do this.
I want to migrate records from one table into another table using a stored procedure.  I have started with a simple procedure (not sure whether it is right or wrong) to print the records based on some condition. Here is the code with which i have tried:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
 DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a VARCHARCHAR(16);
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT user_name FROM discovery_configuration;
   OPEN cur1;
  REPEAT 
    FETCH cur1 INTO a;
     IF a!=' ' THEN 
        select a;
    END IF;
  END REPEAT;
   CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

I need a stored procedure to migrate those records to another table if user_name column is empty. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: You say you want to migrate rows from one table to another but your query is only selecting the user_name. There's no need for this to be a stored procedure, especially if it's a one time move.

Comment: it is not a one time move i have to move records from a table consists of millions of records

Comment: If you need to execute it multiple times then a proc is fine. The number of rows does not matter, a single query will work and there's no need to use a cursor.

Comment: @Tony Can you give me procedure how to do this??

Comment: A procedure is just a wrapper for SQL statements. Create an INSERT statement which SELECTs rows from the source table and place that in your procedure; replacing the cursor code. You should be able to test the query before needing to put it in a procedure.

Comment: @Tony then how to iterate it from starting to ending of a table

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18942/discussion-between-tony-and-shabarinath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does it have to be a stored procedure?

You can copy the records in one query, then delete them with another.

Copy to another table where user_name is empty:

```
INSERT INTO other_table (id, user_name, other)
SELECT (id, user_name, other)
FROM discovery_configuration
WHERE user_name IS NULL OR TRIM(user_name) = '';
```

Then, after you have copied these records, delete from original table:

```
DELETE FROM discovery_configuration WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM other_table);
```

Comment: He wants all rows where user_name is not blank, but I'm just being pedantic. +1

Comment: Even i have tried in that way I have tried like:                 insert ignore into credentialset(version,name,user_name,password,domain_name,transport_type,credential_type,client_id) 
select 0,concat(profile_name,'-','WMI'),user_name,password,domain_name,'HTTP','WINDOWS',client_id from discovery_configuration 
where user_name != ''; but here my requirement is that i must use a stored procedure

Comment: @andrew kuklewicz it is not a one time move i want to iterate this process so that if i execute the stored procedure millons of records present in a table should be migrated.

Comment: This will work for millions of rows. Not sure why a stored proc would be better for more rows, it still has to select and insert the same data.  If it is a requirement, you could wrap this in a stored proc.  If you are very worried about performance, you could create a script that selects to a file, then import the file - that also need not be a stored proc.

Answer (score 1):

Are you inserting all the columns or only user name? if you are inserting all the columns into the another table you should be getting all the columns into the cursor and then insert into the table.. and leave this..based on the info provided above i got that you would like to migrate the data from one table to another table if the username column is null...right?
then you have an easy way to do that.

INSERT INTO A (COUMNS DETAILS) SELECT COLUMNS FROM B WHERE B.USERNAME = ' ';

Try this and let me know..!!

-Rajesh Uddem

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Insert userName into newTable
Select userName from discovery_configuration where cur1 != ' '

Comment: Its not about doing only one statement it should be done iteratively so that it can be used for table consists of large number of records

Comment: It doesnt matter how many records do you have. It will work for thousand or million.